# swift, text in label doesn't change in viewDidAppear()

Tags: swift

I'm new to IOS developtment but I'm programming an app where the user selects a row from a tableView (view 1). The text that the user selected is then displayed in a label on the same screen. When the user pushes the button the text from the label is stored in UserDefaults and the view changes to view 2. Here I have the viewDidAppear() method that gets the String out of the UserDefaults and changes the text of another Label on view 2.

Here is the code for view 1. The function that is called when the button is clicked is called schoolChosenClicked():

```
import UIKit

class ChooseSchool: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var SchoolNames = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var LabelSchoolName: UILabel!


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return SchoolNames.count
    }
    //Set the context
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = SchoolNames[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      LabelSchoolName.text = SchoolNames[indexPath.row]

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SchoolNames.append("Item")
        SchoolNames.append("Item")
        SchoolNames.append("Item")
        SchoolNames.append("")
        self.table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell");
        self.table.dataSource = self
        self.table.delegate = self
        self.table.reloadData()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func schoolChosenClicked(_ sender: Any) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(LabelSchoolName.text, forKey: "chosenSchool")

    }



}
```

[Here is a picture of view 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD5nY.png)

Here is the code for view 2

```
import UIKit

class Login: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var LabelWelcome: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if  var schoolname = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "chosenSchool") as? String
        {
            print("Das ist der Schoolname:" + schoolname+".")
            LabelWelcome.text = "Willkommen bei deiner \(schoolname) App"

        }
    }


}
```

[And here is the picture of the second view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9BDu.png)

In the 2nd picture you can see the Label that says "Name Anmelden". This text actually has to change to "Willkommen bei deiner (schoolname) App" but it does't or after a long period of time.

The value schoolname is well present and the print statement works fine but the LabelWelcome.text =... doesn't work or takes a long time. If I try to set the text in the viewDidLoad() method it works fine.

Do you know why or is there a method that i can call to update the screen?

Thank you,

Manuel

PS: [Here is the screenshot of my login class (view 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfzLd.png)

[Here is the first screenshot of my ChooseSchool class (view 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz1m0.png)

[Here is the second screenshot of my ChooseSchool class (view 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oyZQ.png)

Comment: Are you sure that every IBOutlet and IBAction is connected correctly?

Comment: can you please share debuger log? print("Das ist der Schoolname:" + schoolname+".") print in debuder or not

Comment: @Marco Pace Yes because when I try to set the text in the viewDidLoad() function it works.

Comment: Make sure you have value for LabelSchoolName.text, also while retrieving the value instead of typecasting as string, you can directly take the string instead of object.

Comment: @Anuraj The problem is not the value in: UserDefaults it is that the label in the second view still shows the default value even though I checked the debugger and the value 'content' of the label was set to the right new value.

Comment: can you show your code, how you presenting *Login* Controller?

Comment: @Vats I added the screen shots of the other class

Comment: @ManSe , buddy you didn't show how you are presenting _Login Controller_

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by Login Controller, the class Login is liked to the second view where the Label should change immediately. It only changes when I am doing another action on that screen. For example when I am clicking in a TextView or on a button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select `table cell` or need to add text when clicking on the `button`:

```
@IBAction func schoolChosenClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        LabelSchoolName.text = SchoolNames[indexPath.row]
        UserDefaults.standard.set(LabelSchoolName.text, forKey: "chosenSchool")

    }
```

After that still you getting the problem then add `synchronize` like this when you add your text in `userdefault`(This is not recommended):

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(LabelSchoolName.text, forKey: "chosenSchool")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: _"this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Comment: @Jogendar The problem is not the value in: UserDefaults it is that the label in the second view  still shows the default value even though I checked the debugger and the value 'content' of the label was set to the right new value.